# Proper database configuration

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, configuration

I'm running MySQL 5.5 on Debian 7.8. My entire DB is 2200 MB large (all tables are InnoDB), the mysql process is taking up to 6G RAM but still I think that not evrything is loaded in RAM I have large tables with more than 160 columns and about 500 000 rows. The first 64 columns are indexed with key and when I read them they are loaded instantly but table is allowed to have only 64 keys so the rest of table is extremely slow compared to the first 64 columns.

There are about 350 queries per second in peak hours and the database is consuming up to 160% CPU (Xeon 1246 v3).

I believe that I have something wrong configured but I cannot figure out what. This is my config:

```
join_buffer_size    = 1M
open_files_limit    = 10000
myisam_use_mmap     = 1
query_cache_type    = 1
table_open_cache    = 2000
concurrent_insert   = 2
max_connections     = 3000
query_cache_size    = 16M
key_buffer_size     = 512M
read_buffer_size    = 8M
query_cache_limit   = 4M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 1K
tmp_table_size      = 128M
thread_cache_size   = 5000
sort_buffer_size    = 2M
max_heap_table_size     = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 128M
thread_concurrency      = 8
thread_stack        = 1M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 2M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8192M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
```

Is there anything wrong in my configuration? I have searched net many hours and this config should be ideal for my DB but I am not sure...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64660/discussion-on-question-by-welite-proper-database-configuration).